# Can I directly use Java source code directly in SCILAB, or Is there another way to connect both?

Tags: java, connection, scilab

a friend of mine uses SCILAB for doing his mathematicall "homework" for his studies and he told me, that it should be possible to use Java source code diretly in SCILAB.

The background is that I presented my current Java project and I would like to plot this in 3D, but I haven't done graphical output so far. And he proposed to let SCILAB do the 3D plotting, because there are some ready to use plot scemes implented. But he couldn't tell me how to achive this, so that's why I'm here :).

So my first question is, **if** this is possible to directly use Java source code in SCILAB or at least to some kind of connection between both?
And how this is done! :)

Thank you in advance,

Andreas

Answer (score 1):

in Netbeans first create a java project.
then go to properties of the project you have created and go to libraries..
in libraries "add jar"
now go to the scilab installed directory 
scilab-->modules-->javasci-->jar
in that there will be jar file names javasci.jar
add this to library..
and you are done.
now go to your main file and check out import javasci.*;
and in main function 
Scilab.exec("plot2d(1,3)");

you can see a scilab window

Comment: hi pradyuma and thx for your reply. i did this and with a small"e" in exec it doesn't finde the command and with capital E netbeans finds it at least. but when i want to run it it does this run: The native library javasci does not exist or cannot be found. java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no javasci in java.library.path at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1709) at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:823) [...] i added the javasci.jar (15kb) in properties->libraries, and it is in the dist/lib folder did i do somthing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

at least I found this http://www.scilab.org/product/man/compile_and_run_javasci.html
so it is possible, but I have some problems to get this to work in netbens and eclipse.

has anyone done this before?